# Make datatable fit inside div

Tags: html, css, flask, datatable

I currently have a datatable that is unable to fit in div for some reason, does anyone know how to "squeeze" it toghetter so it will fit fine in my div & would not have to scroll

[image: Table]

Code:

```
<div class="container"  style="margin: 0.1%;">
<table id="myTable" class="display compact" style="width:99%">
    <thead>
        {% for col in column_names %}
    <th>{{col}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in row_data %}
        <tr>
            {% for col, row_ in zip(column_names, row) %}
            {% if col == link_column %}
            
            {% else %}
            <td>{{row_}}</td>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables tend to overflow on purpose, as the columns are too wide.

You have two options:

1. Remove columns to make it so it fits within the div element
2. Set overflow-y to scroll or auto in css on the containing div. This will cut off anything outside the div and allow the user to scroll to see it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Will remove some rows cols